# Qt управление процессом пинга

Tags: c++, qt, сокет, ping, icmp

Доброго времени суток.

Возник вопрос, каким образом можно организовать на C++ (Qt) управление процессом пинга. При помощи QProcess::execute я запускаю ping с параметром -t, и пингую сервер. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, когда именно он ответит на пинг, и, соответственно, мне нужно организовать приём ответных ICMP пакетов, и, помимо этого, как-то отправлять команду остановки процесса пингования. Каким образом это следует организовать? Открыть udp сокет, поймать пакет и убить процесс PING.EXE? Или это можно сделать как-то попроще?

Comment: Зачем городить велосипед? Откройте сокет, соделайте соидинение и сами отправьте/получите пакет. Или найдите исходники пинг - они в сети валяются - модифицируйте их под вашу задачу на любой вкус.

Comment: Вот исходники пинга один из вариантов  http://www.cyberguru.ru/cpp-sources/network/iskhodnik-pinga-ping.html

Comment: Вы можете выполнить команду ping с параметром -n и указать, чтобы отправлялся только один пакет. С помощью QProcess можете отслеживать завершение процесса. Встроенных средств работы с протоколом ICMP в Qt нет.

Comment: *ICMP* - это совершенно отдельный протокол, не имеющий (почти) ничего общего с *UDP*. Ни TCP-, ни UDP-сокеты не принимают ICMP-пакеты, но могут реагировать на состояния, присылаемые посредством ICMP.